# How to convert base64 encoded string to an audio file or any file in flutter

Tags: node.js, flutter, dart, http, google-cloud-platform

I have http request coming from my backend node js server which sends me a base64/binary string. I want to convert that into a file (mp3).

This is a portion of the string I am receiving in flutter (not the whole string):

```
{¸;áÜù|çH?/ÿ?aö§ÌI"ví¯XEÿõÂWû!1î8YÚm¾æàõ¤åù¯F>®*ý&ÿ
```

This is the request I am sending:

```
final res = await http
                .post(
                Uri.parse('*****can't expose the link here sorry*******'),

                headers: {"responseType": "arraybuffer"},
                body: {'type': 'TTS', 'text': 'Hello from flutter.'},

            );
```

This is how I am processing the request:

```
if (res.statusCode == 200) {                  
  debugPrint(res.body);
  var decoded = base64.decode(res.body);
  print('Decoded: $decoded');
  // Converting the decoded result to string
  print(utf8.decode(decoded));
}
```

And I receiving this in the console:

```
. (Same weird characters here)
.
.
I/flutter (23563): dQ¢b²º:KëV<&ùsG(tIPÑI$&e;ÈÑãÛÿÿÿÿÿÎôjuì.ïµJÐ6I
E/flutter (23563): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Invalid character (at character 1)
E/flutter (23563): ÿóDÄ
```

I am new to file converting in flutter. So can anyone Please help me in this. This is working locally in my node js project (not the server but my computer). But I am not able to understand how I can convert that base64 encoded string (Google documentation says that it is a base64 encoded string) into a audio file in flutter.

How I did it in node js:

```
  await axios
.request({
  responseType: "arraybuffer",
  url: "******Sorry can't share the link*********",
  method: "post",
  data: {
    type: "TTS",
    text: "Hello, I am Sam.",
  },
})
.then(async function (response) {
  //console.log(response.data);
  await fs.writeFileSync(
    "D:\\nodejss\\nodejsss\\TTSfile.mp3",
    Buffer.from(response.data)
  );
});
```

Also this is the base64 encoded string in node js console:

```
<Buffer ff f3 44 c4 00 11 d0 05 3c 01 40 18 01 c1 c1 e5 83 f0 11 ff .....(more 00 11 kinda stuff)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't print your data after you decode it. The purpose of base64 (among other things) is to able to view/edit data using regular text editors. If you open your mp3 in editor, or output it to console it will break it.

Comment: That's definitely *not* base 64.